# Import data from a SQL DB Table's Column (a DataSet) into a TextBox?

Tags: c#, asp.net

*Using: ASP.NET 4, SQL 2008, C#*

I'm writing a web app for our projects team to keep track of special project users. One thing they have asked is to export quick lists of data that they use often. For instance, what I'm trying to do here is give the team a button which will populate a TextBox with all the various email addresses that are saved in our SQL DB.

What I've been trying to do is bind the TextBox to a specific column in the DB. I already have a connection to the DB, and I've built a DataSet that queries for that specific column, and it works normally.

My question is, how do I tell ASP.NET to use the data from the DataSet to populate the Textbox? Here is the code I'm working with so far:

```
protected void btnGetNPMEmailAddresses_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    txbResults.Text = "";
    txbResults.DataBind(ObjectDataSource_Designee_EmailAddresses) // ??? My DataSet
    }
```

I'm definitely crawling my way up the C# learning curve. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
   Paul D.

Comment: why do you choose TextBox and not Gridview or ListBox?

Comment: Sleiman - The Projects team is looking to be able to do a quick highlight & copy, so i went with a TextBox for this. I do have it working for a GridView, so I'm satisfied the query itself works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
protected void btnGetNPMEmailAddresses_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // TODO:: Populate ObjectDataSource_Designee
    DataSet dataSet = GetDS(ObjectDataSource_Designee);

    string emails = string.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        emails = emails + dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i]["EmailAddresses"].ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
    }
    txbResults.Text = emails;
}

private DataSet GetDS(ObjectDataSource ods)
{
    var ds = new DataSet();
    var dv = (DataView)ods.Select();
    if (dv != null && dv.Count > 0)
    {
        var dt = dv.ToTable();
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
    }
    return ds;
}
```

Comment: Firoz - 
   I'm running into the same error I receive from Praveen's suggestion: _'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSource' does not contain a definition for 'Tables'_ It seems like both of your suggestions should work, but my code is not accepting that 'Tables'.

Comment: May be you can try converting ObjectDataSource into DataSet and use the DataSet in above code. Url: http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2010/09/how-to-bind-dataset-with.html.

Comment: That did it! :) I replaced (ObjectDataSource_Designee) with my DSO, and it returned the first row of my table over and over. I replaced (Rows[0]) with (Rows[i]) and it worked perfectly! Thank you for all your help! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can't databind to a textbox in ASP.Net.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox_properties

There is no DataSource property. You can manually go through and grab what's in the dataset and put it into the textbox, but not bind it. Do you mean textbox?

Comment: You can in Silverlight/WPF, however, with a dependency property.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are returning only one row and col from the database, you can do something like below:

```
txbResults.Text = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0].Cols[0].ToString();
```

My suggestion would be to use "ExecuteScalar()" method that returns only one value instead of using DataAdapter/Dataset.

Hope this Helps!!

Comment: Thanks Praveen! When I try to use this I'm getting a red squiggle under 'Tables', and the following error:

   _'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSource' does not contain a definition for 'Tables' and no extension method 'Tables' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSource' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)._

   I don't believe I'm missing a 'Using' statement:
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

   I got the same error from Firoz's suggestion, so I'll post this to him as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would say

```
 foreach(DataRow dr in DataTable)
  {
    Textbox.Text = Textbox.Text + dr;
  }
```

if for some reason you HAVE to use a text box